# Save value before redirecting to other page in Angular 4

Tags: angular

I have a scenario, User is editing details on a page but accidentally other page link has been clicked from header menu. Now what I want to do is to save the current page value before redirecting. I am using Angular 4. Any smart way to do it?

Comment: you can use `local storage` for that

Comment: @Sravan Would you please help me with some code.

Comment: https://github.com/tiberiuzuld/angular-auto-save-form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of CanDeactivate Route Guard.
Please refer the link - https://angular.io/api/router/CanDeactivate

Comment: **This is the best answer**. Listening to route events is too heavy for other components, and it implies that you must unsubscribe on destroying your current component. So if you must use `ngOnDestroy`, use it the correct way !

Comment: Thanks. i got the way to do it.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at [Localstorage](https://github.com/Hacklone/angular2-cool-storage). Its a good plugin for controlling the local storage using the browser build in Local Storage API.

For more information about the Local Storage API, read [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage)

Furthermore, you can use the `onDestroy` ([docs](https://angular.io/api/core/OnDestroy)) to store the values that are currently present and the `onInit` to load the variables ;-)

Answer (score -1):

**Note:** If you want to warn user before navigating, you can use a **`canDeactivate` guard** as mentioned in @Basavaraj Bhusani, answer.

[**Here You can find a good Example of Deactivate Guard**](https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-candeactivate-guard-example)

**If you want to store data somewhere and want to use it in app locally, you can use `localStorage`**.

You can all a function from where you can `navigate`,

If you are going to `home component` from `app component`

```
class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private router: Router) {} 

  ngOnInit() {
   // here you can get the data
   localStorage.getItem('form')
  }

  goHome(formData) {
    localStorage.setItem('form', formData)
    this.router.navigate(['home']); 
  }

}
```

**Set Data:** `localStorage.setItem('form', formData)` sets the data

**Get Data:** `localStorage.getItem('form')` gets the data

You can just save the `form Data` and `retrieve` it when coming back to `app component`

Comment: well, [here is an example usage of deactivate guard](https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-candeactivate-guard-example), you can check that, It will be useful for you